# How to switch the visibility setting of two layers in a single action in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

I am new to this forum and wanted to just say a quick hello before asking :)

How do I switch the visibility setting of two layers in Illustrator without having to either see both layers visible or none at all as the in-between step? Please see the attached images, hopefully clarifiying the issue.

Sorry if this is trivial, but it's been vexing me a lot!

Thanks

Viktor[image]

Comment: Hi Viktor, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. I rewrote some things so they're a bit clearer. Feel free to re-edit if the text no longer reflects your question--I didn't get what you wanted to achieve at first, so I might be off.

Comment: No, thank you very much... that makes much more sense. Thanks again :)

Comment: I don't see a way to accomplish this with one step. Layer visibility isn't recordable in an action. The only possible way to do this is with a script, and the script would have to be very specific with layer names.

Comment: Yes, @Bakabaka! That's absolutely right. Ooops, it's gone... anyway, you know what I mean :) 
OK, @Scott, I understand. That's not worth it. I will continue to visually compare the changes by saving a jpg to the desktop and then arrow-key between two images to immediately see the difference... Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I have posted a [script that could be easily repurposed](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36053/18306) for this function:

```
#target illustrator
// Cycle between layervisibility A - B - None - around
// CC BY SA Janne Ojala 2014

layers = app.activeDocument.layers
layer_a = layers.getByName("A") // insert layer names here
layer_b = layers.getByName("B")

if (! layer_a.visible && ! layer_b.visible){
    layer_a.visible =  true;
    layer_b.visible =  false;
} else if ( layer_a.visible && ! layer_b.visible){
    layer_a.visible =  false;
    layer_b.visible =  true;
} else {
    layer_a.visible =  false;
    layer_b.visible =  false;
}
```

This in general is the benefit of writing scripts when you have a few making the next one becomes easier, and easier. So scripting is one of the easiest ways to increase your personal worth.

Comment: Thank you @joojaa that's way cool! Now I have to post a new question "how to install scripts and use them in Ai"... no, only kidding (I can find out myself) Thanks again!

Comment: @krausskopf if you find an answer usefull please upvote them otherwise the site does not know that a good usefull answer was given and rank the question and answeree. Also acceot once you have enough answers. Plus it gives you a few badges.

Comment: cool, understood... although I need min. 15 reputation to upvote... I tried :)

Answer (score 0):

About 4 years past. But still if there are someone who want to learn that how to do it with Adobe's native way. They can find it:

https://forums.adobe.com/message/9855214#9855214

> The following steps may sound pretty complicated, but as you asked for
>   the basic principle you will have to bear the elaboration. In fact, it
>   is a simple procedure and as soon as you have familiarized with it
>   (including setting up custom template files), it is dead easy.
>
> 1. Open a new document and name Layer 1 "Cyan"
> 2. Add three main layers and name them "Magenta", "Yellow" and "Black"
> 3. On each layer draw a shape and colour it according to the Layer's name.
> 4. Save the file as "My_first_Variables.ai"
> 5. Target Layer "Cyan" (click the circle at the right hand of the Layer's name)
> 6. At the bottom of the Variables Palette click the Make Visibility Dynamic button
>
> Now you've created your first Layers Visibility Variable. Continue
>   with …
>
> 7. Target Layer "Magenta" and click the Make Visibility Dynamic button in the Variables Palette
> 8. Target Layer "Yellow" and click the Make Visibility Dynamic button in the Variables Palette
> 9. Target Layer "Black" and click the Make Visibility Dynamic button in the Variables Palette
>
> Done. You have created four Layers Visibility Variables. The next step
>   is to define the Data Sets:
>
> 1. Layers Palette: Show Layer "Cyan" and hide all other layers
> 2. Variables Palette: Click the Capture Data Set button (the camera icon)
> 3. Layers Palette: Show Layer "Magenta" and hide all other layers. Now in the Variables Palette the first Data Set becomes italic, indicating
>      that you can create a new Data Set. So click the Capture Data Set
>      button to define Data Set 2.
> 4. Layers Palette: Show Layer "Yellow" and hide all other layers
> 5. Variables Palette: Click the Capture Data Set button to create Data Set 3
> 6. Show Layer "Black" and hide all other layers. Click the Capture Data Set button to create Data Set 4
> 7. Show all layers and click the Capture Data Set button to create Data Set 5
>
> Done. You have created five Data Sets. Just play arround by toggling
>   them in the Variables Palette (Next/Previous Data Set button or via
>   Popup menu/Flyout menu) and notice one feature among other things: The
>   Variables Palette as a remote control of the Layers Palette. If you
>   like, rename the Data Sets according to the Layers names, for
>   instance.
>
> By the way, showing the Next/Previous Data Set is actionable (that is,
>   a shortcut can be assigned).